# Manipulate History in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've stumped into a problem with my mobile app. After submitting a non-Ajax form and reloading the page, my back button simply reloads the same page since there are, I assume, two entries for the item page.

The flow:

View List Page

View Item Page

Click Edit

Submit Form on Edit Dialog (submits / non-AJAX)

View Item Page

Click Back

View Item Page

Is there any way to exclude the 2nd View Item Page from the history stack?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not talking about capturing the `swipeleft` event, but rather, the click on the physical browser back button, correct?

Comment: I'm referring to the jQuery mobile back button. data-add-back-btn="true"

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem in my application. Following code will give solution for your problem.

```
      window.history.go(-attempt);
```

attempt mean how many time you change (click) the page. I used pagebeforechange event to count the number of attempts.